How to parameterize expression fields in iics CDI
I have a mapping flow like below
Src-->expression-->target
Step 1. I have to read data incrementally based on last modified date-4hrs in source table
Step 2: in expression transformation i have created  variable port like
V_maxdate= add_to_date(last modified date,'HH',-4)

O_maxdate=setmaxvariable($$mqxdate,to_char(v_maxdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ms'))

In-out parameters: maxdate
In source, i filter the data based on maxdate
How to parameterize the expression to change hours from param file
